# Test that last nested division is a particular element

Tags: xml, xpath, schematron

I want a rule to ensure any `div[@class='extend']/div[@class='check']` is positioned last within a `div[@class='chapter']`. Note that there can be other "extend" divisions that have different nested divs (like `div[@class='extend']/div[@class='video']`) whose location is not expected to be last. The nested bit of `div[@class='extend']/div[@class='check']` is tripping me up to write this rule.

I've tried:

XML

```
<test>
<div class="chapter" id="s1">
    <h1 class="title">18.3</h1>
    <div class="intro" id="s2">
        <p>Some intro text here</p>
    </div>
    <!--Incorrect position of div class="extend"/div class="check"-->
    <div class="extend" id="s3">
        <div class="check" id="s4">
            <div class="metadata" id="s5">
                <div class="title" id="s6">
                    <p>Check 18.3</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h1 class="title">Check 18.3</h1>
            <p>This is the Check for Chapter 18.3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!---\-\-\-->
    <div class="sect1" id="s7">
        <h1 class="title">Section text here</h1>
        <p>text text text.</p>
        <div class="extend" id="s8">
            <div class="video">
                <div class="metadata" id="s9">
                    <div class="title" id="s10">
                        <p>Video 18.3</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h1 class="title">Video 18.3</h1>
                <p>This is the Video for Chapter 18.3</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sect2" id="s11">
            <h1 class="title">Section text here</h1>
            <p>text text text.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--div class="extend"/div class="check" should be here as last div of chapter-->
</div>
</test>
```

Schematron:

```
<pattern id="lastdiv">
        <rule context="xhtml:div[@class='check']">
            <assert test="(ancestor::xhtml:div[@class='chapter']/xhtml:div[@class='extend'])[last()]" role="error">This check (with <value-of select="@id"/>) should be the last extend div within a chapter.</assert>
        </rule>
</pattern>
```

However, this does not find my expected result (should produce an error).

Comment: What do you mean with last? last of what? of any element inside of chapter or of any `div[@class = 'extend']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, according to your comment as response of Joshua's answer, I asume that extend/check should be the really last content of chapter (not only the last extent).

This should work:

```xml
    <pattern id="lastdiv">
        <rule context="xhtml:div[@class = 'extend'][xhtml:div[@class = 'check']]">
            <!-- the current extend div -->
            <let name="extend" value="."/>
            <!-- all elements of the current chapter, except of $extend and its descendantes -->
            <let name="chapterElements" value="ancestor::xhtml:div[@class = 'chapter']//* except ($extend, $extend//*)"/>
            <!-- all $chapterElements which have a larger document position (>>) than the $extend-->
            <let name="followingChapterElements" value="$chapterElements[. >> $extend]"/>
            <!-- If there is a $followingChapterElements, the check fails-->
            <report test="$followingChapterElements" role="error">This check (with <value-of select="@id"/>) should be the last extend div within a chapter.</report>
        </rule>
    </pattern>
```

Hope the comments helps to understand.

Comment: Yes, you understood my comment on Joshua's answer correctly. Your rule works like a charm. Quite ingenious. The comments help tremendously. Thanks!

Comment: Once question: why the use of (>>) and not one > or gt ? I've never seen that before.

Comment: `$a >> $b` compares two nodes based on there position in the document. It requires that `$a` and `$b` are exactly one node. `$a > $b` or `$a gt $b` would transform `$a` and `$b` into numbered values so in case of nodes it would compare the content. `$a >> $b` should be equal to `count($a/preceding::node()) > count($b/preceding::node())` (except of the case that `$a` is in a different document as `$b`) but it is much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following?

```
<pattern id="lastdiv">
    <!-- This rule fires on divs that have a class of "extend" and that have a child div with a class of "check" -->
    <rule context="xhtml:div[@class='extend' and xhtml:div/@class='check']">
    <!-- The assert tests that the div is the last div within its parent -->
        <assert test="position() = last()" role="error">This check (with <value-of select="@id"/>) should be the last extend div within a chapter.</assert>
    </rule>
</pattern>
```

Note that this solution asserts that the div with `class="extend"` is the last child (of any kind) within the `chapter`. If the `chapter` could have other elements after that `div` (including other `div` elements without `class="extend"`), this assertion would not work correctly.

Comment: Thanks. This isn't working as expected, though. I need to ensure the extend/check is the last chunk of content within a chapter. This isn't checking chapter at all.